# Plugin Development - Class Constructor Not Firing wp_enqueue_style action hook

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Writing my first Wordpress plugin that uses a Class approach.

It is being called on a page via a shortcode. In testing, the shortcode is working and the shortcode specific php file is being loaded.

However, the 2 add_action calls are not firing:

```
//Register Styles
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', array( $this, 'register_styles' ) );

//Register Scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', array( $this, 'register_scripts' ) );
```

When I test with var_dump, the register_styles/scripts functions are not even running, yet all other functions called in __contruct() are.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array ( 'Lipstick_Consultation', 'init' ));

if (!class_exists('Lipstick_Consultation')){

class Lipstick_Consultation{

    public static function init() {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        new $class;
    }

    /**
     * @since 1.0
     */
    public function __construct() {

        //get contstants
        $this->setup_constants();

        //get file includes
        $this->includes();

        //Register Styles
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', array( $this, 'register_styles' ) );

        //Register Scripts
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', array( $this, 'register_scripts' ) );

        $this->register_shortcodes();

        return $this;


    }

    /**
     * Include our Class files
     *
     * @access private
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return void
     */
    private function includes() {

        /****SHORTCODES****/
        //[slider_person]
        require_once LC_DIR . 'inc/shortcodes/slider.php';
    }

    /**
     * Setup plugin constants
     *
     * @access private
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return void
     */
    private function setup_constants() {

        // Plugin information
        define( 'LC_VERSION',       '1.0.0' ); // Current plugin version
        define( 'LC_URL',           plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
        define( 'LC_DIR',           plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
    }

    /**
     * Register Styles
     *
     * @access public
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_styles() {

        //main style file
        wp_register_style( 'consultation_style', LC_URL . "assets/css/style.css", array(), time(), 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'consultation_style' );

        //styles for full page plugin
        wp_register_style( 'lc_full_page_style', LC_URL . "assets/css/jquery.fullPage.css", array(), time(), 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'lc_full_page_style' );

    }

    /**
     * Register Scripts
     *
     * @access public
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_scripts() {

        //Script that makes full width/height/page divs
        wp_register_script( 'lc_full_page', LC_URL . "assets/js/jquery.fullPage{SUFFIX}.js", array( 'jquery' ), time() );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'lc_full_page' );

    }

    private function register_shortcodes(){
        add_shortcode("lipstick_person","shortcode_person_slider");
    }

}
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no action called `wp_enqueue_script`, it's `wp_enqueue_scripts`, plural, and both scripts and styles should be enqueued on that action.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if( !class_exists('SiteOrigin_Installer_Theme_Admin') ) {
    class SiteOrigin_Installer_Theme_Admin {

        function __construct(){
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_admin_page' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_admin_sub_page' ), 15 );
            add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ), 15 );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_so_installer_theme_headers', array( $this, 'theme_headers_action' ) );
        }

        static function single(){
            static $single;
            if( empty($single) ) {
                $single = new SiteOrigin_Installer_Theme_Admin();
            }

            return $single;
        }

        /**
         * Add the theme admin page
         */
        function add_admin_page() {
            if ( empty ( $GLOBALS['admin_page_hooks']['siteorigin'] ) ) {
                add_menu_page(
                    __( 'SiteOrigin', 'siteorigin-installer' ),
                    __( 'SiteOrigin', 'siteorigin-installer' ),
                    false,
                    'siteorigin',
                    false,
                    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/img/icon.svg',
                    66
                );
            }
        }

        function add_admin_sub_page(){
            add_submenu_page(
                'siteorigin',
                __('Install Themes', 'siteorigin-installer'),
                __('Install Themes', 'siteorigin-installer'),
                'install_themes',
                'siteorigin-themes-installer',
                array( $this, 'display_themes_page' )
            );
        }

        /**
         * @param $prefix
         */
        function enqueue_scripts( $prefix ){
            if( $prefix !== 'siteorigin_page_siteorigin-themes-installer' ) return;
            wp_enqueue_style( 'siteorigin-installer-themes', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/css/themes.css', array( ), SITEORIGIN_INSTALLER_VERSION );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'siteorigin-installer-themes', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/themes.js', array( 'jquery' ), SITEORIGIN_INSTALLER_VERSION );
        }

        /**
         * Display the theme admin page
         */
        function display_themes_page(){

            if( !empty( $_GET['install_theme'] ) && !empty( $_GET['theme_version'] ) ) {
                // The user is installing a theme
                $this->display_install_page();
                return;
            }

            $themes = SiteOrigin_Installer::single()->registered_themes();
            $latest_versions = get_transient( 'siteorigin_installer_theme_versions' );
            if( empty($latest_versions) ) $latest_versions = array();
            $updated = false;

            foreach( $themes as $slug => $theme ) {
                if( !empty( $latest_versions[$slug] ) ) continue;

                $version = SiteOrigin_Installer::single()->get_theme_version( $slug );
                if( $version === false ) continue;

                $latest_versions[$slug] = $version;
                $updated = true;
            }

            if( $updated ) {
                // Cache for 12 hours
                set_transient( 'siteorigin_installer_theme_versions', $latest_versions, 43200 );
            }

            // We need to know the current theme
            $current_theme = wp_get_theme();

            // Increase the current themes weight
            foreach( $themes as $slug => $theme ) {
                if( $slug == $current_theme->get_stylesheet() ) $themes[$slug]['weight'] = 999;
            }

            // Sort the themes by weight
            uasort( $themes, array( $this, 'sort_theme_compare' ) );

            include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/tpl/themes.php';
        }

        /**
         * Comparison function for sorting
         *
         * @param $a
         * @param $b
         *
         * @return int
         */
        function sort_theme_compare( $a, $b ){
            if( empty($a['weight']) || empty($b['weight']) ) return 0;
            return $a['weight'] < $b['weight'] ? 1 : -1;
        }

        /**
         * Display the plugin install page
         */
        function display_install_page(){
            check_admin_referer( 'siteorigin-install-theme' );
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php'; // Need for upgrade classes

            $slug = !empty( $_GET['install_theme'] ) ? $_GET['install_theme'] : false;
            $version = !empty( $_GET['theme_version'] ) ? $_GET['theme_version'] : false;

            if( empty($slug) || empty($version) ) {
                wp_die( __('Error installing theme', 'siteorigin-installer') );
            }

            ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <?php
                // This is where we actually install the theme

                $theme_url = 'https://wordpress.org/themes/download/' . urlencode( $slug ) . '.' . urlencode( $version ) . '.zip';

                $title = sprintf( __('Installing Theme: %s'), $slug . ' ' . $version );
                $nonce = 'install-theme_' . $slug;
                $url = 'update.php?action=install-theme&theme=' . urlencode( $slug );
                $type = 'web'; //Install theme type, From Web or an Upload.

                $upgrader = new Theme_Upgrader( new Theme_Installer_Skin( compact('title', 'url', 'nonce', 'plugin', 'api', 'type') ) );
                $upgrader->install( $theme_url );

                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        function theme_headers_action(){
            if( empty($_GET['_sononce']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['_sononce'], 'theme_info' ) ) exit();
            if( empty( $_GET['theme_slug'] ) || empty( $_GET['theme_version'] ) ) exit();

            // header('content-type: application/json');
            $data = SiteOrigin_Installer::single()->get_theme_data( $_GET['theme_slug'], $_GET['theme_version'] );
            echo json_encode( $data );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
SiteOrigin_Installer_Theme_Admin::single();
```

Comment: Hi Jeffery, Welcome to WPSE! It would be great if you could explain how the code answers the question. Just posting some code won't be helpful.